# If you add a color button to the ckeditor, an error will occur?

Tags: ckeditor

Adding a color button on the ckeditor does not produce a color button.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ckeditor.js:264 Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "colorbutton" was not found at "http://localhost/your_recipes_app3/assets/js/ckeditor/plugins/colorbutton/plugin.js?t=J0BE".
    at CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:264)
    at e (ckeditor.js:259)
    at Array.x (ckeditor.js:259)
    at w (ckeditor.js:259)
    at HTMLScriptElement.CKEDITOR.env.ie.e.$.onerror (ckeditor.js:260)
```

I try to use the ckeditor but if I put e.g. the colorbutton plugin, the textarea disappears. Here is how I tried:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'recipe_description', {
                               extraPlugins: 'colorbutton',
                                 } );
```